# How can i convert a .bin (binary) to a .json (json) file with linux?

Tags: linux, binary-files, json, file-conversion

I don't know how to convert a binary file back to a .json file. I have been searching for a while now and could not find a single answer, well,  i did but none of which worked.

Can this be done in just a smiple command line code or does it need an application or something to do so? If you could help, that would be really good.

Thanks

Comment: What does this `.bin` file contain? What is its format? How do you map the contents of this format into JSON? Without a complete, precise, unambiguous, exact, objective specification of the input format and the output format, including any and all rules, exceptions, corner cases, special cases, and edge cases, this question is un-answerable. It would also help if you could provide sample inputs and outputs that demonstrate those rules and exceptions, so that answerers can test and verify their solutions.

Comment: this question is gibberish

Comment: could be related to https://www.blend4web.com/en/forums/topic/3634/

Comment: Sounds like the [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). This would be an incredibly uncommon thing to do making me think you're miss-interpreting other instructions. Why are you trying to convert a `.bin` file to `.json`?

Answer (score 0):

A .bin file extension can contain anything including but not generally  a text file.

A json file is a text file, so it is possible it could be a json file badly named.

Duplicate the original file

Try opening it up in a text editor like gvim (google it).
Gvim is an opensource editor available for PC and linux.

If the result looks like a jumble of letters then check the first few lines.
Often a .bin file will have a some text at or near the start of the file which you can google to get more info.

If the file when opened looks like a json file (again google) then just save with the ending ".json" added to the filename and you are done.

This is simple on linux and PC command line and when saving from gvim, more complicated when the operating system is "helping" you.

If you are on linux try "strings" for more clues, and post those clues here.

Good luck, when you succeed award yourself the rank of computer detective cadet level 3, you will deserve it.
With luck it will take you about 30 minutes to get to a result. The result might be it is not practical to convert it to a .json file.

Let us know your progress.

BTW Though I am classed as a new contributor, I have been at this game for over 40 years.

Comment: could be related to https://www.blend4web.com/en/forums/topic/3634/